# Implementation of Strtol function - cast

Tags: c, constants

I have my own implementation of strtol and it works correctly i think. It looks as below:

```
long strtol(const char *nPtr, char **endPtr, int base)
{
  const char *start;
  int number;
  long int sum = 0;
  int sign = 1;
  const char *pos = nPtr;
  if (*pos == '\0')
    return 0;
  start = pos;
  while (isspace(*pos))
  {
    ++pos;
  }
  if (*pos == '-')
  {
    sign = -1;
    ++pos;
  }
  if (*pos == '+')
    ++pos;
  if (base == 16 || base == 8)
  {
    if (base == 16 && *pos == '0')
      ++pos;
    if (base == 16 && (*pos == 'x' || *pos == 'X'))
      ++pos;
    if (base == 8 && *pos == '0')
      ++pos;
  }
  if (base == 0)
  {
    base = 10;
    if (*pos == '0')
    {
      base = 8;
      ++pos;
      if (*pos == 'x' || *pos == 'X')
      {
        base = 16;
        ++pos;
      }
    }
  }
  if ((base < 2 || base > 36) && base != 0)
  {
    errno = EINVAL;
    return 0;
  }

  while (*pos != '\0')
  {
    number = -1;
    if ((int) *pos >= 48 && (int) *pos <= 57)
    {
      number = (int) *pos - 48;
    }
    if (isalpha(*pos))
    {
      number = (int) toupper(*pos) - 55;
    }

    if (number < base && number != -1)
    {
      if (sign == -1)
      {
        if (sum >= ((LONG_MIN + number) / base))
          sum = sum * base - number;
        else
        {
          errno = ERANGE;
          sum = LONG_MIN;
        }
      }
      else
      {
        if (sum <= ((LONG_MAX - number) / base))
          sum = sum * base + number;
        else
        {
          errno = ERANGE;
          sum = LONG_MAX;
        }
      }
    }
    else if (base == 16 && number > base
        && (*(pos - 1) == 'x' || *(pos - 1) == 'X'))
    {
      --pos;
      break;
    }
    else
      break;

    ++pos;
  }

  if (!isdigit(*(pos - 1)) && !isalpha(*(pos - 1)))
    pos = start;

  if (endPtr)
    *endPtr = (char*) pos;
  return sum;
}
```

However I have a question about last line :

```
*endPtr = (char*)pos;
```

Why do i have to cast pos to (char), endPtr and pos are both pointers to char, in other case the warning will say that :
Assignment makes pointer from integer without cast.
Thanks for help

Comment: `*endPtr` = `char*`, `pos` = `const char*` not same type really.

Comment: A lot of the standard C library functions have broken signatures.  A side effect of string literals being of type char* instead of const char*.  Too late to fix that.

Comment: Your implementation has a bug: `char *endptr; strtol("0x!", &endptr, 16); puts(endptr);` and you will see it prints "!" (correct behavior is printing "x!").

Comment: Another bug: `long a = strtol(" xf", &endptr, 16); printf("%d", a);` Correct: 0 (no digits scanned). Wrong: 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because they aren't of same type.

`*endPtr` is `char*` type

`pos` is `const char*` type.

Comment: @user2511527: If you are happy really,don't forget to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

`endPtr and pos are both pointers to char`

This is false. `pos` is defined as

```
const char *pos= nPtr;
```

And `endPtr` as

```
char **endPtr
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by others because `const char * p`is not the same as `char * p`.

However, if you'd change the function's signature to be:

```
long strtol (const char * nPtr, const char ** endPtr, int base);
```

the cast would not be necessary.

Comment: Yes , you are right after changing

    *endPtr = pos; 

Is correct.